# How to convert int to time (e.g. "1930" to "19:30") and get difference between start and end time in hours and minutes (HH:MM)?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 columns on my table that contains time in and out. I need to subtract them and get the spent hours even converting them to time or any other way.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FELData](
    [RCIN1] [numeric](4, 0) NOT NULL,
    [RCOUT1] [numeric](4, 0) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

RCIN1        RCOUT1     Desire Result
150          1930       17:40
615          1747       11:32
410          1830       14:20
400          1600       12:00
```

here is what I have done so far but is not returning the right numbers

```
SELECT rcin1, rcout1, DATEDIFF(mi,
    CAST(STUFF(RIGHT('0'+CAST(rcin1 AS VARCHAR(8)),4),3,0,':') AS DATETIME),
    CAST(STUFF(RIGHT('0'+CAST(rcout1 AS VARCHAR(8)),4),3,0,':') AS DATETIME)
    )/60.0 AS [Hours]   
FROM FELData;

RCIN1        RCOUT1     Returning
150          1930       17.66
615          1747       11.53
410          1830       13.25
400          1600       12.83
```

How can I fix this?

**Update**

Sometimes there might be user data entry errors like

```
RCIN1        RCOUT1     Returning
49          1930        Should return 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does almost what you want, but it fails to discern that 49, 1930 is *bad* data. How do you know?

Since the data you have is numeric there is no need to convert it to prose, split it, parse it, convert it, recombine it, ... . Just do the math!

**[UPDATED CODE]**

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( RCIn1 Numeric(4,0), RCOut1 Numeric(4,0) );
insert into @Samples ( RCIn1, RCOut1 ) values
  ( 150, 1930 ), ( 615, 1747 ),  ( 410, 1830 ), ( 400, 1600 ),
  ( 49, 1930 ); -- This is allegedly "bad" data, but no explanation is given.
select * from @Samples;

with
  -- Numeric values converted to instances of TIME datatype.
  Times as (
    select RCIn1, RCOut1,
      Cast( DateAdd( minute, Floor( RCIn1 / 100 ) * 60 + RCIn1 % 100, 0 ) as Time ) as RCIn1Time,
      Cast( DateAdd( minute, Floor( RCOut1 / 100 ) * 60 + RCOut1 % 100, 0 ) as Time ) as RCOut1Time
    from @Samples )
  -- Calculate delta times.
  select *, Cast( DateAdd( minute, DateDiff( minute, RCIn1Time, RCOut1Time ), 0 ) as Time ) as DeltaTime
    from Times
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is storing time as a number,
but here is how I would convert a number into a time datatype:

```
declare @timeNumb int = 1500

    select 
        convert( time , (
reverse( substring( reverse( convert( varchar, @timeNumb) ) , 3, 2 ) ) + ':' +
reverse( substring( reverse( convert( varchar, @timeNumb) ) , 1, 2 ) )
                        ) 
                )
```

After which using the datediff() should give you the interval length you are looking for.

Comment: And using right( '0000' + convert( varchar ,  @timeNumb ) , 4 ) would be how I make sure the value is 4 char long. As for handing bad data - use a case statement or do a cleaning pass prior to calculation.

Comment: No need - for a complete solution use HABO's post above.  I am also not sure why 49 is "bad" data- since 00:49 is a valid time (49 minutes past midnight).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-- temp table for data sample
DECLARE @FELData AS TABLE
    (
      [RCIN1] NUMERIC(4, 0) ,
      [RCOUT1] NUMERIC(4, 0)
    )
INSERT  INTO @FELData
        ( RCIN1, RCOUT1 )
VALUES  ( 150, 1930 ),
        ( 615, 1747 ),
        ( 410, 1830 ),
        ( 400, 1600 )

--Solution
SELECT  T.[RCIN1] ,
        T.[RCOUT1] ,
        RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), T.M / 60), 2) + ':'
        + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), T.M % 60), 2) AS Duration
FROM    ( SELECT    FD.* ,
                    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                             CONVERT(TIME, STUFF(RIGHT('0'
                                                       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), FD.[RCIN1]),
                                                       4), 3, 0, ':')),
                             CONVERT(TIME, STUFF(RIGHT('0'
                                                       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), FD.[RCOUT1]),
                                                       4), 3, 0, ':'))) AS M
          FROM      @FELData AS FD
        ) T
```

output result

[image]